# SQL byte truncate

Tags: sql, truncate, bitset

My input is a varchar payload (that is actually made of hexadecimal characters). I would like to convert it to bits, then truncate the result to decode it.
I already have a built-in function (hexstrtovarbin) that works correctly and that converts varchars into varbinaries.

For example, for an input "4d", I would like to convert it into bits (01001101) then truncate the first 6 digits, before converting them into an integer (and get eventually 19).

```
DECLARE @payload varchar(4), @binarypayload binary(1), @converted smallint;

SET @payload = '4d';
SET @binarypayload = hexstrtovarbin(@payload);
SET @converted = CAST(SUBSTRING(@binarypayload, 1, 6) AS int)
```

If I proceed like this, @converted takes 77 as value. This is because @binarypayload value is "TQ==" (and not actual bits), so the substring does not truncate it.

I have tried to use bit data type, but could not store more than 1 of them.

Would anyone know how to get the actual bits in order to truncate them?

Comment: Isolate the byte you want and then integer divide by 4. `cast(substring(0x4d0000, 1, 1) AS int) / 4`

Comment: Thank you very much! Very simple indeed.
This method enables me to use the right part of the truncature as well, using %. As I need to use the truncated 2 bits with the following 8 bits, I can do:
`SET @converted2 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@binarypayload, 1, 1) AS int) % 4 * 256 + CAST(SUBSTRING(@binarypayload, 2, 1) AS int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be messy but this is my answer, according to your data in the question:

```
declare @intvalue int
set @intvalue=  CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(max), '4d', 2) )

declare @vsresult varchar(16)
declare @inti int
select @inti = 16, @vsresult = ''
declare @Input varchar(16)

--translating ex string in binary digits

while @inti>0
  begin
    select @vsresult=convert(char(1), @intvalue % 2)+@vsresult
    select @intvalue = convert(int, (@intvalue / 2)), @inti=@inti-1
  end


set @Input= left(@vsresult,LEN(@vsresult)-2)  -- here your input string without last two digits,   00000000010011 


--now return integer value
 DECLARE @Cnt tinyint = 1
    DECLARE @Len tinyint = LEN(@Input)
    DECLARE @Output bigint = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1) AS bigint)

    WHILE(@Cnt < @Len) BEGIN
        SET @Output = @Output + POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len - @Cnt, 1) * 2 AS bigint), @Cnt)

        SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    END

select @Output
```

Comment: Works well, thank you! But I'll go with the 1 line solution from shawnt00